# tensorflow estimator passes train data through some weird normalization

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, batch-normalization

**Problem Description**

I'm using tensorflow Estimator API, and have encountered a weird phenomenon.
I'm passing the exact same `input_fn` to both training and evaluation, and for some reason the images which are provided to the network are not identical.
They seem similar, but after taking a closer look, it seems that evaluation images are ok, but train images are somewhat distorted.

After loading them both, I noticed that for some reason the training images go through some kind of ReLu. I affirmed it with this code, which operates on `mat_eval` and `mat_train`, which are tensors that `input_fn` provides in evaluation and train mode:

```
special_relu = lambda mat: ((mat - 0.5) / 0.5) * ((mat - 0.5) / 0.5 > 0)
np.allclose(mat_train, special_relu(mat_eval))
>>> True
```

**What I thought and tried**

My initial thought was that it is some form of BatchNormalization. But BatchNormalization is supposed to happen within the network, and not as some preprocess, shouldn't it?
What I recorded (using `tf.summary.image`) was the `features['image']` object, passed to my `model_fn`. And if I understand correctly, the `features` object is passed to `model_fn` by the `input_fn` called by the Estimator object.

Regardless, I tried to remove the parts in the code which are supposed to call the BatchNormalization. This had no effect. Of course, I might have not done that in the right way, but as I said it I don't really think it is BatchNormalization.

**Code**

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging

from dcnn import modeling
from dcnn.dv_constants import BATCH_SIZE, BATCHES_PER_EPOCH
from dcnn.variant_io import get_input_fn, num_variants_in_ds

logging.set_verbosity(logging.INFO)
new_checkpoint_name = lambda: f'./train_dir/' \
                              f'{datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m %H:%M:%S")}'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    model_name = 'small_inception'
    start_from_checkpoint = ''
    # start_from_checkpoint = '/home/yonatan/Desktop/yonas_code/dcnn/train_dir' \
    #                        '/2111132905/model.ckpt-256'
    model_dir = str(Path(start_from_checkpoint).parent) if \
        start_from_checkpoint else new_checkpoint_name()
    test = False
    train = True
    predict = False
    epochs = 1

    train_dataset_name = 'same_example'
    val_dataset_name = 'same_example'
    test_dataset_name = 'same_example'
    predict_dataset_name = 'same_example'

    model = modeling.get_model(model_name=model_name)
    estimator = model.make_estimator( \
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        model_dir=model_dir,
        params=dict(batches_per_epoch=BATCHES_PER_EPOCH),
        use_tpu=False,
        master='',
        # The target of the TensorFlow standard server to use. Can be the empty string to run locally using an inprocess server.
        start_from_checkpoint=start_from_checkpoint)

    if train:
        train_input_fn = get_input_fn(train_dataset_name, repeat=True)
        val_input_fn = get_input_fn(val_dataset_name, repeat=False)
        steps = (epochs * num_variants_in_ds(train_dataset_name)) / \
                BATCH_SIZE
        train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=val_input_fn,
                                            max_steps=steps)
        eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=val_input_fn,
                                          throttle_secs=1)
        metrics = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec,
                                                  eval_spec)
        print(metrics)
```

I have plenty of more code to share, but I tried to be concise. If anyone has any idea why this behavior happens, or needs more information, let me know.

Comment: I have a hard time linking your described issue with the code you shared. What are `mat_train` and `mat_eval`? Are they the output of the `input_fn`? Are they the output of the network? I really suggest that you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help us to help you, but also, you might find the issue by yourself while crafting it,

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, @Lescurel!
`mat_train` and `mat_eval` are the tensors which are loaded by the `input_fn`, I'll add an edit, thanks for the opportunity to clarify.
I provide an example in this github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45428